# Set a div's HTML to contain its own unique value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a page that allows an admin to edit articles within the site.

I've developed a small script that runs a PHP while loop, spitting out images within a div. Each div is given a unique value with a key, in this case `$i`, thus giving every div within the loop a value of '1', '2', '3' etc etc.

**Note:** There is no issue with my PHP, the keys are working perfectly fine within the while loop.

**The issue:**

All I'm simply trying to do is set the `.html` of the 'num' div to its value, this is to illustrate what the current image id is. I could easily do this by putting the key in-between the opening and closing div tags, however PHP being server-side will not do for me as I am allowing the user to remove images if they chose to, which would mess up the order. I also want to avoid using AJAX for what should be a simple function. I just thought I'd throw that in here before anyone suggests it.

The keys are showing fine in console and are all working correctly on the PHP side of things, however the jQuery I seem to be having a rough time with.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it'd be appreciated.

Thanks, Rich.

**jQuery:**

```
var myVal = $('.num').attr('value');
$(this, '.num').html(myVal);
```

**PHP (this works fine):**

```
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
$images = unserialize(base64_decode($row3['image']));
$imgCount = count($images);
echo "<ul class='text2'>";
    foreach ($images as $index => $img_url){
        $i = $index + 1;
        echo "
<li data-id='$i'>
<div class='x'></div>
<div class='num' style='margin: 0 0 0 30px; display: inline; padding: 5px 0 0 0;' value='$i'></div><br/><br/>
<img src='images/".$img_url."' width='400px' height='auto' style='border: 1px solid #fff;'/>
<input type='hidden' name='oldCnt' id='oldCnt' value='$imgCount' data-id='$index'/>
<input type='hidden' name='img2[]' id='img2[]' value='$img_url'/>
</li>

";
    }
echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: `value` isn't a valid attribute for DIVs, it's only used in input elements.

Comment: If you want to have user-defined attributes, use `data-val='$1'` and `.data('val')` to get it.

Comment: @Barmar http://jsfiddle.net/0sehvhde/

Answer (score 2):

`$('.num').attr('value')` will always retrieve the value of the **first** `.num` element on the page, not each element. You need to use a `.each()` loop. Or you can take advantage of the fact that `.html()` can be given a function argument, and it will loop automatically.

```
$('.num').html(function() {
    return $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Comment: This worked man, cheers. I'll mark you right in a couple of minutes when it lets me.